# Preventing Child Widget Rebuilds in card_swiper in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using the card_swiper package in my Flutter app to create a swiper with multiple cards. However, I've noticed that when I interact with the swiper (e.g., swipe to the next card), the child widgets within each card are being rebuilt, which is causing performance issues.

Here's a simplified version of my code using card_swiper:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('card_swiper Widget Rebuild Issue')),
      body: MySwiper(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MySwiper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Swiper(
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        // Each card contains complex child widgets
        return MyCardWidget(index: index);
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyCardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const MyCardWidget({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyCardWidgetState createState() => _MyCardWidgetState();
}

class _MyCardWidgetState extends State<MyCardWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Complex child widget content here
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Text('Card ${widget.index}'),
    );
  }
}
```

In this setup, each card contains complex child widgets, and these child widgets are being rebuilt every time I swipe to a new card in the swiper. This behavior is causing performance issues.

Is there a way to prevent the child widgets within each card from rebuilding when swiping between cards using card_swiper? Are there any optimization techniques or workarounds I can implement to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:appinio_swiper/appinio_swiper.dart';
```

can you please check https://pub.dev/packages/appinio_swiper package

```
 SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.92,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.60,
            child: AppinioSwiper(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              loop: true,
              backgroundCardsCount: 2,
              swipeOptions: const AppinioSwipeOptions.all(),
              unlimitedUnswipe: true,
              controller: controller,
              unswipe: _unswipe,
              onSwipe: _swipe,
              onEnd: _onEnd,
              cardsCount: randomQuestions.length,
              cardsBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var cardIndex = randomQuestions[index];
                return FlipCardsWidget(
                  bgColor: cardColor,
                  cardsLenght: randomQuestions.length,
                  currentIndex: index + 1,
                  answer: cardIndex.options[cardIndex.answer],
                  question: cardIndex.question,
                  name: widget.name,
                );
              },
            ),
          )S
```